# "Double" reverse node reference

Tags: views, nodes

On the Website im currently building, i am using the Node Reference Module to link Activities to Persons, so i can view which Persons have participated in a Acticity.
I also setup views and panels to list the Activity each Person has done on the Person node.

Now i want, in the Activity node, to show other Activities the Persons participating have done:

*Person A has done Activity A and Activity B*
*Person B has done Activity B and Activity C*
*Person C has done Acticity A B and C*
*Person D has done Acticity A*

When I look at the Activity B node, I want to see something like this:

*Other Activities the Persons have participated in:*
*Person A: Activity A*
*Person B: Activity C*
*Person C: Acticity A and Activity C*

How would i do this? I found this (http://drupal.org/node/1257946) topic, but there he is using 3 nodetypes.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Anybody? I think with a one value field this would be possible via Relationships and Contextual Filters, but I am struggling with the multiple Values :(.